# Server not loading after removing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, uninstallation

After setting up wordpress I realized it was not what I wanted and have tried to remove it. I have deleted all of the wordpress files and database but now when I try to load the webpage through Chrome using the ip as the address nothing appears.

The console in the developer tools says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" and nothing else.

How do I get apache to load the webpage and is their something I missed when uninstalling wordpress?

EDIT: After reinstalling apache a page now loads and shows this page

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've also deleted the .htaccess file? It's a hidden file, so you probably have to make hidden files visible in your FTP software.

Comment: No I haven't, could you recommend a way of doing this?

Comment: What FTP software are you using?

Comment: Apache, Is that what you mean. I am very new to all of this

Comment: Nope, how did you remove WordPress? What software did you used to do that?

Comment: I deleted all of the files that I could find and then used the terminal to delete the database and then used 'sudo apt-get remove wordpress'

Comment: Alright, so if you cd into the directory that WordPress was in, and then do the command "ls -la" (without the quotes), do you see an .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand that last part?

Comment: Open your terminal, use the command "cd" to go to the directory where WordPress was previously installed, then use the command "ls -la".

Then you are getting a list of all the files (including the hidden one's) that are in that directory.

Check if there is an .htaccess file in that list.

Comment: Yes there is and I've deleted it but the same error is still happening

Comment: You're sure it's gone? Have you tried restarting Apache?

Comment: Yes and unfortunately the same message

Comment: That's strange.. Are there any other files in that directory that can maybe cause this error?

Comment: Not that I can see, this is the website I followed to install it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: If you don't use that directory for other things, I recommend just deleting or remove all the files that are in it. There must be something that's messing up your server.

Comment: I can load all the other files fine when I add the extension (eg.'http://127.0.0.1/cssIndex.css') but I cant load the main 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php'

Comment: What is in index.php?

Comment: It is the home page for my website, the only php is an echo and basic html, css and javascript linked to it but all of these can be seperatly loaded